Angular universal routing issue
i have problem with Angular Universal when i load homepage http://localhost:85 page loads but in view source i get
<body class="h-100 v-robots">
    <app-core class="h-100">
      <div id="loading"></div>
      <div class="loadingSplash"><div class="loadingSplashImage"></div></div>
    </app-core>
  </body>
</html>

this is my routing

export const ROUTES: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: () => import('./homepage/homepage.module').then(m => m.HomepageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    loadChildren: () => import('./account/account.module').then(m => m.AccountModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'page/:name',
    loadChildren: () => import('./generic-static-page/static-page.module').then(m => m.StaticPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'promotion/:slug',
    loadChildren: () => import('./landing-page/landing-page.module').then(m => m.LandingPageModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'expert-advice',
    loadChildren: () => import('./expert-advice/expert.module').then(m => m.ExpertModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'contact',
    loadChildren: () => import('./contact/contact.module').then(m => m.ContactModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'checkout',
    loadChildren: () => import('./checkout/checkout.module').then(m => m.CheckoutModule)
  },
  {
    path: 'wishlist',
    loadChildren: () => import('./wishlist/wishlist.module').then(m => m.WishlistModule)
  },
  {
    path: '**', 
    loadChildren: () => import('./exceptions/exceptions.module').then(m => m.ExceptionsModule)
  }
];```

homepagemodule


@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule, SharedModule, 
    RouterModule.forChild([
    {
      path: '',
      component: HomepageComponent,
    },
  ])],
  declarations: [
    HomepageComponent,
    FeaturedCategoriesComponent,
    PostComponent,
    PromoSliderComponent,
    PostImagePipe,
    DecodeUrlPipe
  ]
})
export class HomepageModule {}


when i add custom path like
 {
      path: 'test',
      component: HomepageComponent,
    },

localhost:85/test page loads and in view source everything is correct
this is my server.ts
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone-node';
import '@angular/compiler';
import { ngExpressEngine } from '@nguniversal/express-engine';
import * as express from 'express';
import { join } from 'path';
import { AppServerModule } from './src/main.server';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { existsSync } from 'fs';
import compression from 'compression';

import * as zlib from 'zlib';

// Polyfill for getComputedStyle for SSR
global.getComputedStyle =
  global.getComputedStyle ||
  function () {
    return {
      getPropertyValue: function () {
        return '';
      },
    } as any; // Type assertion to 'any'
  };
import { productRouter } from './server/routes/product.route';
import { productlistRouter } from './server/routes/productlist.route';
import { searchRouter } from './server/routes/search.route';
import { promotionRouter } from './server/routes/promotion.route';
import { loggerMidware } from './server/helpers/winston.helper';
import { SsrRequest } from './server/interfaces';
import { setGlobals } from './server/helpers/set-globals.helper';
// Constants for server configuration
export const DIST_FOLDER = join(process.cwd(), 'dist');
const PORT = parseInt(process.env.PORT, 10) || 85;

// Function to configure and return the Express app
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const indexHtml = existsSync(join(DIST_FOLDER, 'index.original.html')) ? 'index.original.html' : 'index';

  // Use Brotli compression
  server.use(
    compression({
      // Specify Brotli as the preferred encoding
      brotli: {
        enabled: true,
        zlib: {
          level: zlib.constants.BROTLI_MAX_QUALITY, // Use maximum Brotli compression level
        },
      },
    })
  );

  // Configure Angular Universal to use the ngExpressEngine
  server.engine(
    'html',
    ngExpressEngine({
      bootstrap: AppServerModule,
    })
  );

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', DIST_FOLDER);
  server.disable('view cache');

  // Serve static files
  server.get(
    '*.*',
    express.static(DIST_FOLDER, {
      maxAge: '1y',
    })
  );
  // Application routes
  server.use('/product', productRouter);
  server.use('/productlist', productlistRouter);
  server.use('/search', searchRouter);
  server.use('/promotion', promotionRouter);

  // Server-side rendering of Angular routes
  server.get('*', loggerMidware, (req: SsrRequest, res: express.Response) => {
    setGlobals();
    res.render(indexHtml, { req, providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: req.baseUrl }] });
  });

  return server;
}

// Function to start the Express server
function run(): void {
  const server = app();
  server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
  });
}

// Ensure server runs only when this module is the entry point
declare const __non_webpack_require__: NodeRequire;
const mainModule = __non_webpack_require__.main;
const moduleFilename = (mainModule && mainModule.filename) || '';
if (moduleFilename === __filename || moduleFilename.includes('iisnode')) {
  run();
}

export * from './src/main.server';


iam trying to get correct data in view source in localhost:85

Any errors in the console server side for the nodejs process that runs universal? Usualy if don't have the source code it meands that an error prevented the page to render, and then you only get the content from index.html
